# Use a suitable substitution to show these integrals are equal

Tags: integration, substitution

> $$\int\frac{\cos(\tan^{2}t)}{1+t^2}dt=\int\cos(t^2)dt$$

Please help, I have tried substituting in different values such as $u = \tan^2(t)$, however, I am not getting very far with it.

Comment: Please do not force people to go look at images not included in your message. You may use MathJax to render mathematical symbols. [Here is a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is a homework question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$u=\tan t, du=(1+\tan ^2t) dt$$ and then change the dummy variable back to $t$